# How do I make subplots from normalized figure coordinates only?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have normalized figure coordinates`(left, bottom, right, top)` of subplots in a figure. These coordinates are generated by a different software. The number of subplots is not fixed. I'm trying to generate a figure using these coordinates.

Here is a small example of what I've tried.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
rects=[[0, 0.5, 0.75, 1],[0.25, 0, 1, 0.5]]
for i in range(2):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
    ax.plot([1, 2, i])
    ax.set_xlabel(i)
    gs.tight_layout(fig, rect=rects[i])
plt.show()
```

This generates the figure correctly as per my requirement.

[image: Pyplot Output]

But when I tried to implement the same in The object-oriented interface the output is different.

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = Figure()
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
rects=[[0, 0.5, 0.75, 1],[0.25, 0, 1, 0.5]]
for i in range(2):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
    ax.plot([1, 2, i])
    ax.set_xlabel(i)
    gs.tight_layout(fig, rect=rects[i])
fig.savefig('test')
```

[image: OO Output]

Is my approach correct? Why output of `pyplot` is different from Object Oriented Interface? How do I get it working in Object Oriented Interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little bit by coincidence that the first code works at all. I wouldn't rely on that.

Now it seems you want to position the axes by coordinates. In that case, one would rather use `add_axes`, and calculate the extends from the rectangles,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
rects=[[0, 0.5, 0.75, 1],[0.25, 0, 1, 0.5]]
for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
    a,b,c,d = rect
    ext = [a,b,c-a,d-b]
    ax = fig.add_axes(ext)
    ax.plot([1, 2, i])
    ax.set_xlabel(i)

plt.show()
```

The resulting figure may not make too much sense, which is due to the coordinates in use. Maybe, those are not the ones you meant to be using?

---

A similar figure to the one in the question may also be produced with a single gridspec, like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2,3) 

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:2])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1:])

for i, ax in enumerate([ax1, ax2]):
    ax.plot([1, 2, i])
    ax.set_xlabel(i)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `add_axes` takes rect values in bounds `(left, bottom, width, height)`. My inputs are in extents `(left, bottom, right, top)`. So I tried to convert using `(left, bottom, right-left, top-bottom)`. But padding is messed up.

Comment: I see. I updated the answer accordingly; and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: But padding is not coming correctly. y-axis labels of top subplot is clipped. x-axis of top subplot is aligned with upper border of bottom subplot. x-axis labels of bottom subplot is clipped. Using `plt.tight_layout(True)` doesn't help.

Comment: No, sure, because you specified the coordinates and the axes are where they are specified. Why would you want to have some coordinates first, and then later have the axes *not* at those coordinates?

Comment: What should I do to get a figure similar to the first figure in the Question? Should I give some margin while converting from bounds to extents?

Comment: Just use a GridSpec, but without those coordinates and let matplotlib arange the plots to look nice?

Comment: Sorry for so many questions. The coordinate values in extents format is generated by another software. I don't have control on that.

Comment: I added another code, using gridspec. I think I still don't understand why you let some other software generate some coordinates for you, so maybe I cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please remove the second code it is not required. Sorry for annoying you :)

Comment: Used `ext=[a+0.12, b+0.1, c-a-0.16, d-b-0.15]` to get acceptable margins between subplots.